# in w8/w8.1 whats the keyboard shortcut for 'List View' in windows explorer?

Tags: windows

When I'm viewing a folder, how to do I quickly switch to list-view? In windows 7 I do it all the time using `Alt + V + L`, however I cannot find out what it is in windows 8 / 8.1 / 10 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such shortcut according to Microsoft. You can use Alt + V + L in Windows explorer to go to "layout" in "View" tab then use the arrow keys to select your favorite layout.

See: [Shortcut list @ Microsoft.com](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts=windows-8)